Quarkus messaging - Validating Connector outgoing messages
We are using Quarkus to consume events from Kafka, perform some enrichments, and push them to an internal system over HTTP using a custom connector.
We need to validate that the enriched events conform to a given schema before dispatching them,
and send the invalid events to a DLQ.
We tried to perform the validation with an interceptor, but could not find a way to gracefully fail the message this way.
Is this possible?
Or is there another recommended approach for handling this kind of validation?

According to the documentation, the message should be nacked when you throw an exception in your method and skipped when you return null.
And I'm not sure whether this also works inside an Interceptor.
See also this section.
